# Difference between 'everything to me' & 'everything for me'

Tags: vocabulary

I am confused between

> she's everything to me

and

> she's everything for me

Can anyone explain which one should i use.

Comment: Without some context to set it up, the second one sounds weird. The first one is fine and means *in my life, she is so important that nothing else matters*. I think the problem with the second one is that it sounds as though you are trying to say *in my opinion, she's everything*, which would be odd because *she's everything* can only really be a personal feeling of yours, and you know your own personal feelings - you don't really have opinions about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usage of '**to me**' and '**for me**' seems similar, but it has a slight difference.

Usage of '**to me**' is **more personal.** It Indicates how much a **thing/person values** to you.

Let's look at the following example.

> The car is important **to me** because my dad gave it to me.

Here, it shows how **valuable** the car is to you.

On the other hand,

Usage of '**for me**'  indicates the benefit.

Let's look at the following example.

> The car is important **for me** because it helps me with transportation.

Here, **for me** is used to tell the listener about the benefits of the car.

[Refer this link for more information](https://www.speakconfidentenglish.com/prepositions-to-for/)

***YOUR CASE***

The choice depends upon the reason for you to utter those lines.

Using **to me** in your case would make more sense because you are using the word **everything**. The word **everything** means that you are talking about someone you love/like (In your case). So if you want to show how much you love/like somebody, you can use **to me**.

When you use **for me** in your case then it should be followed by a benefit.

For example,

> She is everything for me because she takes care of me.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -2):

Both are correct, but, I think, the variant with 'to' is preferable.

(Look at my comment below.)

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

***everything***

1a: 
all that exists

b: all that relates to the subject

2: all that is important

// you mean 
everything ***to*** me

According to Reverso.context.net:

And he does everything ***for*** me.

I mean, my wife means everything ***to*** me.